# localhost host not working on XAMPP

Tags: xampp, localhost

I am facing same problem to the thread. I've gone through all the suggestions provided in the solution. I've searched all possible solution but nothing gonna workout.

"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/817745/localhost-not-working-on-xampp-both-service-apache-mysql-are-fine"

I've ensured : 
1. Xampp is successfully started (in log) but it is not receiving any request(checked access.log). 
   also ensured that it is running on port 80 in config file.

1. confirmed status of application using netstat

C:\Documents and Settings\user>netstat -aon | grep 80
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       3524

1. Checked host file in /windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts and has only one entry

127.0.0.1       localhost

1. skype teamviewer or other application are closed and configured not to use port 80.
2. ensured that windows firewall allows http process to use port 80.
3. pinged localhost, 127.0.0.1 and my ip (192.168.1.2). localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1
4. tried different urls http:// localhost http:// localhost:80 http:// 127.0.0.1 http:// laptop-name but nothing works. browser just waits for response (spaces after http to allow links in this post)
5. ensured that there is no loop in index.php(it is untouched) and also has index.html. also tried diffent paths

nothing gonnna work out. I am irritated and I dont want to format my machine.  please help....

Answer (score 1):

when this happens to me it is usually Skype taking over the default localhost address

Answer (score 1):

Check on command prompt

```
netstat -a -b
```

And close any other application like **skype** etc using `80 port`.

Answer (score 0):

Try stopping IIS. It worked for me.

1. Select Start, then type IIS in the search box
2. select Internet Information Services Manager
3. In the manager on the right under "Manage server"select "stop"

Answer (score 0):

I was having an issue with Last.fm that is very similar to yours, and I found that it was a software conflict.

The Last FM scrobbler application would not finish installing on my new build because it couldn't login or authenticate my username.  I tried the regular scrobbler application and then tried the beta desktop program on Windows 7 64 bit.  I suspected Skype or TeamViewer, but even after stopping or exiting those programs, neither versions of the installation would log in to the services.

- The beta desktop application actually authenticated on 127.0.0.1 (random port) through my internet browser, but my browser would time out trying to send data over the port.
- I checked and edited my HOSTS file in Windows, but that didn't fix the issue either.
- Pinging 127.0.0.1 worked, but pinging any variation of the port would time out.

Finally, I decided to uninstall the Windows 7 Firewall Control program made by Sphinx Software.  Mind you, I had set the firewall to be disabled at start up (clean start-up - all startup programs disabled through MSConfig).

I made sure that the firewall program was not running at all in my services.  However, after uninstalling the software, even without restarting my computer, 127.0.0.1 opened up on all ports and my Last.fm scrobbler finally connected and finished installation.

So, it may be a hidden setting that can only be undone by uninstalling programs (even programs that aren't running).

Answer (score 0):

For me localhost was not the correct address.

Type into cmd "hostname" and use that as the url.

CMD -> hostname

If that doesn't work try just the ip address of the server (or computer)

Answer (score 0):

I stored my website folder in xamp/htdocs (windows machine). Then I started apache on the XAMP control panel. My pages rendered successfully when I called http://localhost/mysite/index.html.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Please see this first [how-to-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

This question is answered before, obviously, you can add your answer here. But You Need to understand some points before answering. First, don't add an answer which is previously added with the same code or suggestion. Second, don't add an overly complicated answer if the user has asked very specifically about the problem and what he needs to solve this. Third, You can add a comment if you want to suggest anything regarding the answer or question.